# Is there a possibility to export data.frames stored insides two lists in R?

Tags: r, list, for-loop

I have again a list problem.
I have seven different dataframes stored inside a list. And six of these lists are together stored in another list. (Sounds complicated, I know :D)

So, e.g.
data(mtcars)

```
df1 <- tail(mtcars)
df2 <- mtcars[1:5, 2:10]
df3 <- mtcars
df4 <- head(mtcars)
lower_list1 <- list(df1, df2, df3, df4)
```

and then I have 5 other lower_lists (lower_list2, lower_list3, lower_list4)
that are stored in the list: upper_list

```
upper_list <- list(lower_list1, lower_list2, lower_list3, lower_list4)
```

and now I want to export all of these dataframes in own directories, that I created before with the help of a RegEx:

```
files <- str_extract(names(upper_list), pattern = "^([a-z])(_)([a-z])([1-9])")

for(i in 1:length(files)) {
  dir.create(paste0("./Exports/Taxa-Tables/", files[i]))
}
```

what I tried so far is:

```
  for (f in upper_list) {  # f are the lists inside the upper list
    
      
      lapply(seq_along(f), 
           function(i) write.table(f[[i]], 
                                   paste0("./parent/", str_extract(names(upper_list)[i], 
                                   pattern = "^([a-z])(_)([a-z])([1-9])")]), 
                                   row.names = FALSE, sep = "\t")) 
}
```

I think the problem is somewhere here:

```
str_extract(names(upper_list)[i] 
# I am not sure if it is names(upper_list)[[i]] or names(upper_list[[f]], both times I get the error. With the example outside the loop it works, there I wrote 
`names(upper_list)[[1]]` #' to get the first list of the upper_list
Maybe one could include a command to get the index of the list?
```

The error I get is:

```
Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
  cannot open file './parent/lower_list1/': Permission denied
```

If I try the command outside the loop for one of the lower_lists, it works. Do you have any idea how to solve this problem? I hope it is understandable. If not, I could try to upload images that support my description?

Looking for you helpful ideas :)
Kathrin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the codes below using the `tidyverse` package. Each lower list's data will be saved into their respective directory which I named `d1` to `d4`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(upper = upper_list, dir_name = paste0("d", 1:4), 
             file_name = list(paste0("file_", 1:4, ".csv")))  %>%
             mutate(dir_vec = map(dir_name, ~rep(.x, 4)),  
             path = map2(dir_vec, file_name, ~file.path(.x, .y))) 

# create the 4 directories
walk(df$dir_name, dir.create)

# save the data stored in list into their directory
map2(df$upper, df$path,  ~walk2(.x, .y, write.csv))
```